# Help With Particular Regular Expression - Not Containing Some String

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How do I say, in regular expressions:

Any portion of a string beginning with a capital letter, containing at least one space character, not containing the string
`" _ "` (space underscore space), and ending with the string "!!!" (without the quotes)?

I am having trouble with the "not containing" part.

Here is what I have so far:

```
[A-Z].* .*!!!
```

How do I modify this to also specify "Not containing ' _ '"?

It does not need to be the specific string " _ ".  How can I say "not containing" ANY string?  For instance not containing "dog"?

*Edit*: I'd like the solution to be compatible with Php's "preg_replace"

*Edit*: Examples:

**Examples for " _ ":**

Abc xyz!!!           <---Matches

Hello World!!!       <---Matches

Has _ Space Underscore Space!!!  <--- Does Not Match

**Examples for "dog":**

What a dog!!!   <--- Does not match, (contains "dog")

Hello World!!!  <--- Matches

Comment: Hello, what language are you using? Perl Reg.exps? ECMAScript?

Comment: Can you post a few examples of valid/invalid strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x(?!y)` expression matches `x` only if it is not immediately followed by `y`. So, this seems to be the thing you want:

```
[A-Z](?!%s)(.(?!%s))* (.(?!%s))*!!!
```

Where `%s` is your forbidden string.

Answer (score 1):

Any possible regex for this would be probably much more complicated than two regexes. One like yours: `[A-Z].* .*!!!` and the second applied on matched strings and checking whether `_` is contained.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to "capture" the matching portion of the string, so I require a single regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Any capital; have an optional string of everything except an underscore, a space, and then the everything except underscore again, followed by three exclamation marks.

```
[A-Z][^_]*[ ][^_]*!!!
```

Comment: How would I apply this in the case of the "dog" example, in my edit above?

Answer (score 0):

First test your string for any occurance of " _ ", since that is a no match. Then check for what you want.

That's what I would do instead of spending a lot of time trying to figure out one regular expression for it.

Here's a nice site for testing your expressions: [Nregex](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/)

**Edit**: I read some more on your question and see that my answer wasn't really good, so here's another attempt. A modification of one of the expressions above:

```
[A-Z](?! _ )(\w(?! _ ))* (\w(?! _ ))*!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Z]([^ ]*(?! _ ) ?)*!!!
```

***Edit:*** I missed your requirement for at least one space.  The below regex includes that requirement:

```
[A-Z][^ ]* (?!_ )((?! _ ).)*!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to resolve it via `grep`'s `-v` option (if I'm on Linux and/or can use `grep`).

So search for something, then skip the uninteresting parts.

```
grep something <INPUT> | grep -v uninteresting
```

Without grep (damn windows, without admin rights) but with Vim:

```
vim -c "v/i'm searching for this/d" -c "g/and don't need this/d" -c "w checkoutput" <INPUT>
```

(This opens , then deletes every line what does not match what you need, then deletes every line, what you does not need, then save the results as `checkoutput`. Which you should check.)

HTH

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice little program in which you can built your regex together with testing it.

http://software.marioschneider-online.de/?C%23%3A_RegEx_Test

Comment: This is not really an answer to Joshua's question, and is therefor (IMO) better suited as a comment.