# Regular expression for a string that is not the prefix of some other particular string

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression that would find all instances of the string "&", but not if the instance is the prefix of the string "&nbsp;".

For example, it would match the "&" in "John & Paul", but not the "&" in "John &nbsp; Paul".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) [(see this answer as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966318/help-with-particular-regular-expression-not-containing-some-string/3966578#3966578). The syntax would generally be something like:

```
&(?!nbsp;)
```

Which matches any ampersand not followed by `nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be :

```
\s&\s
```

You can try your regex on [this website](http://www.rubular.com/)

Comment: i love it, it allows to easily test the regex